# Rails set timer on server request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, time

I have a Rails project in which the user can submit a request through a form. If the request takes too long for the server to process (say, more than 30 seconds), I would like the server to terminate and return to the user "Sorry, it's taking too long for the server to process your request." Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rack-timeout gem](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) does just that.

Comment: Thanks, Gavin. Do you happen to know how to use it? I'm quite confused by the doc. I added the line `gem 'rack-timeout'` to my Gemfile and ran `bundle install`. (It shows `Using rack-timeout (0.0.4) `) Then I submitted a request to my server. It clearly hanged for more than 15 seconds without returning anything to me. What am I missing?

Comment: @Mika have you added the initialization file: `config/initializers/timeout.rb`? Also, make sure you restart your server too.

Comment: I'm not sure how I should restart my server... I'm not running a development server.

Comment: @MikaH. if you're not running a development server then running `touch tmp/restart.txt` will trigger a server restart on most setups.